# Merging float columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame, `df`, which looks like this:

```
Index   count    mean     std
1       101.0    8.15    3.26
2       102.0   13.20   11.48
3       101.0  235.15  186.76
4        84.0  420.49  637.59
```

I need to merge the `'mean'` column and the `'std'` column so that I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Index   count    mean(std)    
1       101.0    8.15 (3.26)
2       102.0   13.20 (11.48)
3       101.0  235.15 (186.76)
4        84.0  420.49 (637.59)
```

How can I achieve this is pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do it this way:

```
df['mean'] = df['mean'].map(str) + ' (' + df['std'].map(str) + ')'
df = df.drop(['std'], axis=1).rename(columns={'mean':'mean(std)'})
```

timings:

```
In [425]: df = pd.concat([df]*10**5)

In [426]: df.shape
Out[426]: (400000, 3)

In [427]: %timeit df['mean'].map(str) + '( ' + df['std'].map(str) + ')'
1 loop, best of 3: 786 ms per loop

In [428]: %timeit df['mean'].map('{:,.2f}'.format) + df['std'].map('({:,.2f})'.format)
1 loop, best of 3: 845 ms per loop

In [429]: %timeit df['mean'].astype(str) + '(' + df['std'].astype(str) + ')'
1 loop, best of 3: 1.51 s per loop
```

Conclusion:

`map` seems to be faster than `astype`

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string and combine:

```
df['mean(std)'] = df['mean'].map('{:,.2f}'.format) + df['std'].map('({:,.2f})'.format)

print(df)      
        count    mean     std       mean(std)
Index
1        101    8.15    3.26      8.15(3.26)
2        102   13.20   11.48    13.20(11.48)
3        101  235.15  186.76  235.15(186.76)
4         84  420.49  637.59  420.49(637.59)
```